# How can I dynamically change the text of a tooltip with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, and wish to change the text of a tooltip with Javascript.

I've had a search around the questions but can't seem to find anything illuminating.

Basically I need to get the tooltip text then replace it with something else, without disturbing the underlying HTML.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Can you show use your HTML? Tooltip - do you mean alt and title attributes?

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tooltip.shtml ??

Comment: I mean the Title attribute, sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: This is what I am trying to access: the title here:

Comment: <div id="logo">
      <a title="http://www.google.com" aria-label="Link action for logo" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" border="0">
        <img width="202" height="49" aria-hidden="true" alt="logo" src="0-logo-bd.png" border="0">
      </a>
    </div>

Comment: I want to change the title to something else without touching the HTML.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that `elid` is the ID of the element carrying the tooltip:

```
document.getElementById('elid').setAttribute('title', '_new content_');
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick example, I assume you mean the title attribute?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/wmzLs7gp/1/

HTML:

```
<a title="some text" id="blah">hi</a>
<button id="mybutton">change tooltip</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click',
    function () {
        // These following two lines are the part that matter
        var anchor = document.getElementById('blah');
        anchor.title = 'new tooltip';
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is dependant on where you are getting the data from that you wish to replace the tooltip text with. However you can replace the tooltip text as follows:

You will need to reference the tooltip element in javascript.
Next you need to set the text that you wish to change.

Basic selectors in javascript look like this

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('yourElementId');
```

See the example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3690va6h/) that will change the text as soon as you run. Hopefully this should provide a basis on how to make the change.

Comment: Assuming I have understood exactly what you're looking to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean my Tooltip, I'm assuming you mean the `alt` attribute on an image or the `title` attribute you get some other HTML tags, with such lack of information I'd recommend looking into the `setAttribute` method, for example

```
document.getElementById("myIdReference").setAttribute("alt", "My new Alt text");
```

There's more info here...

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Turns out there were other title elements, so this worked:<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#logo a').removeAttr('title');
            $('#logo img').removeAttr('title');
            $('#logo).attr('title', 'Click here to go to our website');
      });
</script>  All sorted using JQuery in the end.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myIdReference").title = 'my tooltip text'
```